# (javascript) how to i get the ID of an element i've selected?

Tags: javascript

let's say I selected a bunch of elements by class. how do i find out what the ID is of each of my returned elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access the id property

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    elements[i].id
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
   elements[i].getAttribute('id');
}
```

Comment: Uhm, `++i` instead of `i++` ?

Comment: Meh, whatever you prefer, I have heard that ++i is a little more efficient than i++, but I don't think it really matters all that much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 function selectedDivs (theClass) {
                         var allHTMLTags=document.getElementsByTagName("div");

                        for (i=0; i<allHTMLTags.length; i++) {
                        //Get all tags with the specified class name.
                        if (allHTMLTags[i].className==theClass) {
                        allHTMLTags[i].getAttribute('id');
                        }
                        }
                        }
```